# The hashCode() method for the following case: two sets are equal when they have at least one element in common?

Tags: java, equals, hashcode

I am currently facing a scenario where I have String tuples (of size 2), and two tuples should be considered equal if they have at least one element in common. I have the following class implementing this idea:

```
public class MyTuple
{
    private List<String> list = Arrays.asList(new String[2]);

    public List<String> getList()
    {
        return list;
    }

    public void set(String firstElement, String secondElement)
    {
        list.set(0, firstElement);
        list.set(1, secondElement);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other)
    {
        if (other instanceof MyTuple) {
            return !Collections.disjoint(this.list, ((MyTuple) other).getList());
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

However, according to the `hashCode()` contract:

> If two objects are equal according to the equals(Object) method, then calling the hashCode() method on each of the two objects must produce the same integer result.

How can I override my `hashCode()` method not to violate the contract?

Comment: No need because `MyTuple` could never be a key in a collection.

Comment: Why not? I am using Spark and MyTuple will be the key in <K, V> paired RDDs.

Comment: Return a constant for hashCode(). It will certainly screw performance when using MyTuple in any collection that makes use of the hashcode, but with your "dynamic" equality rule its the only way to satisfy the contract.

Comment: I up voted this because it is working in practice. However, as @leeyuiwah mentioned, I am violating another contract in my equals() method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before considering `hashCode()`, I think you should reconsider your design of `equals()` first.  I don't think you can implement `equals()` and fulfill the required contract -- especially the one on **transitivity**

From: [Java Doc of `Object#equals()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object))

> The equals method implements an equivalence relation on non-null
>   object references:
>
> - It is reflexive: for any non-null reference value x, x.equals(x)
>     should return true.
> - It is symmetric: for any non-null reference values
>     x and y, x.equals(y) should return true if and only if y.equals(x)
>     returns true.
> - It is transitive: for any non-null reference values x,
>     y, and z, if x.equals(y) returns true and y.equals(z) returns true,
>     then x.equals(z) should return true.
> - It is consistent: for any
>     non-null reference values x and y, multiple invocations of x.equals(y)
>     consistently return true or consistently return false, provided no
>     information used in equals comparisons on the objects is modified.
> - For
>     any non-null reference value x, x.equals(null) should return false.

Why? I can construct three objects of your `MyTuple`:

- A = {x1, x2}
- B = {x2, x3}
- C = {x3, x4}

where `x1`, `x2`, `x3`, `x4` are all distinct.  Now I have

- A.equals(B) returns true
- B.equals(C) returns true
- C.equals(A) returns false

And they violate the contract on transitivity.

I think you should consider using another relationship of your own (perhaps `partialEquals()`) so you don't have to obey the contract.  But then
you also *cannot* use the method like `equals()` and expect `MyTuple` to work,
for example, in `HashMap`, `HashSet`, etc

Comment: Unfortunately, partialEquals() will not help, since I need to perform 'ByKey' operations in Spark on MyTuple as a key. All of these operations rely on equals() and hasCode(). Apparently, I need to re-think this. Thank you.

Comment: @Tkh -- You can consider **canonicalizing** your `MyTuple` -- by sorting the element in `list` (by some order), so if you have `{x1, x2}` and `{x2, x1}`, they are always canonicalized as `{x1, x2}` (assuming `x1 < x2` by some order).  When that is done, you can have a `equals()` (and `hashCode()` too) that always operate on `list` after it is sorted.

Comment: @TKh -- (continuing ...) Not knowing the exact application scenario of yours.  That idea of canonicalization may or may not work for you.